# Azure Apns Hub not working with production Certificate

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, azureservicebus

I have successfully tested an azure apns hub in sandbox mode. Now when I try to switch  over to production, nothing works. I have read the tutorials, and i'm sure that I generated the production certificate right. Does anybody have an idea what the problem would be? At some point I think I have read that while I was using an Iphone to test the sandbox apns, it may not work after switching to production.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am facing same issue!

Comment: Have a look at my post

Comment: I am having same issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging some more, I figured out what the problem was. I had to run my application with the production certificate. That means, that I could not test the production APNS running the app through Xcode, since xcode would automatically install the development certicicate that is linked to the sandbox apns. Run the app outside of xcode, with the production certificate.